# jquery ui buttons not getting rendered correctly to the table row upon button click

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, button, css-tables

Problem I am facing is that when I add some data to the textboxes and click "create", the buttons being rendered in the third column are losing their jquery ui css. 
Following is the fiddle link:
http://jsfiddle.net/evazrp6o/1/

And here is my html:

```
<div id="protocolParMain">
<table class="userTable">
<tr>
    <th class="uName">Username</th>
    <th class="uLevel">Level</th>
    <th class="uOpt">Options</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="cellEditable" contenteditable="false">User 1</td>
    <td class="cellEditable" contenteditable="false"> User</td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="del">Delete</button>
        <button class="apply">Apply</button></td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td class="cellEditable" contenteditable="false">User 2</td>
    <td class="cellEditable" contenteditable="false"> User</td>
    <td><button class="edit">Edit</button>
        <button class="del">Delete</button>
        <button class="apply">Apply</button></td>
</tr>

 </table>
 <p>Add User</p>
<div class="clear"></div>
<label for="usr">Username</label>
<input type="text" name="usr" id="usr">
<label for="pwd">Password</label>
<input type="password" name="pwd" id="pwd">
<button id="create">Create</button>
```

And here is my jquery:-

```
$("#create").button().click(function(){


    var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
    var td_username=$('<td></td>',{
        text:  $("#usr").val()
    }).appendTo(tr);

    var td_level=$('<td></td>', {
        text: "User"
    }).appendTo(tr);

    var td_buttons=$('<td></td>',{
        html: '<button class="edit">Edit</button> <button class="del">Delete</button> <button class="apply">Apply</button>'
    }).appendTo(tr);

    $(".userTable").append(tr);

});


    $(".edit").button().click(function() {
        var currentItem = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
            $.each(currentItem, function(){
                $(this).prop("contenteditable",true);
                $(this).css("border-color","red");
            });
    });

    $(".del").button().click(function(){
       var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(currentItem,function(){
            $(this).remove();
        });
    });

    $(".apply").button().click(function(){
        var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
        $.each(currentItem,function(){
            $(this).prop("contenteditable",false);
            $(this).css("border-color","");
        });

    });
```

And you will find the rest in the fiddle. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/evazrp6o/4/)**.

**Your code works great after 3 changes.**

1. You have to use **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** event instead of `click()` so you can deal with fresh elements added with javascript e.g. (edit, del, apply buttons), so replace all :

   ```
   $("selector").button().click(function() {
   ```

   By :

   ```
   $(document).on('click', 'selector',function(){
   ```
2. You have to init css style of all the buttons in your page using :

   ```
   $(document).find('button').button();
   ```
3. In click event related by `create` button, try to apply `jquery-ui` style to the 3 buttons firstly and after that add them to the `tr` :

   ```
   $(tr).find('button').button();
   $(".userTable").append(tr);
   ```

---

**Full JS :**

```
//Init all page buttons 
$(document).find('button').button();

$(document).on('click', '#create',function(){

    var tr=$('<tr></tr>');
    var td_username=$('<td></td>',{
        text:  $("#usr").val()
    }).appendTo(tr);

    var td_level=$('<td></td>', {
        text: "User"
    }).appendTo(tr);

    var td_buttons=$('<td></td>',{
        html: '<button class="edit">Edit</button> <button class="del">Delete</button> <button class="apply">Apply</button>'
    }).appendTo(tr);

    $(tr).find('button').button();
    $(".userTable").append(tr);

});


$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
    var currentItem = $(this).parents("tr").find("td");
    $.each(currentItem, function(){
        $(this).prop("contenteditable",true);
        $(this).css("border-color","red");
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.del',function(){
    var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
    $.each(currentItem,function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.apply',function(){
    var currentItem=$(this).parents("tr").find("td");
    $.each(currentItem,function(){
        $(this).prop("contenteditable",false);
        $(this).css("border-color","");
    });

});
```

Hope this helps.